# What is the meaning of twist in OPE?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics, effective-field-theory

In Operator Product Expansion (such as explained in Peaking) there appear a quantity for an operator called twist, defined to be $d-s$ where $d$ is the scaling dimension of the operator and $s$ is it's spin. Is there a geometric meaning to that? What exactly is being twisted here?